# Electric field in the center of hemisphere shell without double/triple integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

I'm trying to derive the electric field in the centre of a solid hemisphere of radius $ R $ where the charge is distributed uniformly. I have seen different methods involving double/triple integrals but my current knowledge is beyond that and anyway I want to do it the "hard way".

My approach is:

- Calculate the electric field produced by a semi-circle (think of it as a bent rod) of uniform charge. Caring only about the electric field component that doesn't cancel
- Knowing the electric field of a semicircle, calculate the electric field of the hemisphere shell, someway creating that shell from the adding lots of semicircles
- Knowing the electric field of a hemisphere shell, calculate the solid hemisphere integrating the shells from 0 to R

I don't have issues with the first step. The electric field in the axis that doesn't cancel to my calculations and [other resources](http://www.phys.uri.edu/gerhard/PHY204/tsl329.pdf) this result:

$$ E_y = \frac{2k\lambda}{R} = \frac{\lambda}{2\pi\epsilon_0R} = \frac{Q}{2\pi^2\epsilon_0R^2} $$

However, I have issues with how to approach the second step. Where now $ Q $ is the charge of the entire hemisphere shell, the electric field component produced by an entire semicircle in the center that won't end up cancelled is:

$$ dE_y = \frac{dQ}{2\pi^2\epsilon_0R^2} \sin(\theta) $$

But I'm sure in how to express $ dQ $ as a function of the angle or even if the approach of adding infinitesimal thin semicircles while rotating them around the center works to create a shell.

Comment: I think this is better posted in [Physics StackExchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: If you make it out of semicircles, think of those as having a thickness $Rd\theta$. Then the surface area of this band is $dS=Rd\theta\cdot 2\pi r$. Here $r$ is the distance to the axis perpendicular to the semicircle. If the total charge on $2\pi R^2$ is $Q$ then on the band is $dQ=Q\frac{dS}{2\pi R^2}$

Comment: I think that if you divide the hemisphere into circles parallel to the open face you would have an easier approach. All you need is the electric field of a ring of radius $R\sin\theta$ at a distance $R\cos\theta$ from the center, along the axis perpendicular to the ring. Then the electric fields of the rings just add up.

Comment: Thanks @Andrei, your second approach worked well. Regarding $ dS $ in your first comment. Why is $ 2 \pi R $? The length of the semicircle is $ \pi R $

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I forgot a divide by 2.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the surface area of the semicircle either. In that case with the semicircles having a surface area of $ dA = \pi r^2 d \theta $ How would I get the surface of the hemisphere shell? The integration over theta would from from 0 to $ \frac{\pi}{2} $ but that doesn't result on $ 2 \pi r^2 $